# jQuery add text before href attribute

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, css-selectors

How can I add text to before a href attribute?

Example:

```
<a href="/page/subpage">Link!</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/page/subpage">Link!</a>
```

I have tried this, which is not working:

```
$('http://www.example.com').insertBefore('a[href=]');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a callback function with `attr`:

```
$('a[href]').attr('href', function(index, href) {
    if (href.indexOf('http') === 0) {
        return href;
    } else {
        return 'http://www.example.com' + href;
    }
});
```

The more cryptic way would be to use the [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base):

```
$('<base href="http://www.example.com/">').appendTo('body');
```

Or just put it into your HTML:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

It'll force all relative URLs to resolve relative to this URL.

Comment: @roasted: `prop` returns an absolute URL. So does `this.href`, BTW.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined

Comment: @user2086252: You have links without a `href` attribute. Change the selector (see my edit).

Comment: "prop returns an absolute URL" that's what i saw in jsfiddle. Really interesting behaviour (quite strange imo) http://jsfiddle.net/bNTPe/

Comment: @roasted: Sort of. The attribute is the value of the `href` attribute. The property is the URL that the link points to.

Comment: That's make sense. Thx Blender. BTW, +1 as most complete solution here

Answer (score 2):

Just change href attribute:

```
$('a:not([href*="//"])').attr(function(_, href){
    return "http://www.example.com" + href;
});
```