# jQuery: adding prefix to any url (.attr)

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I cant seem to figure this out as simple as I am sure it is, but I am trying to use jQuery to modify all URL's for selected elements, not to replace, but to add something before the link. I was curious when i stumbled on
blankrefer.com.

I am trying to make links more secure by changing them like so:

- from:http://www.blah.com/blah
- to:http://blankrefer.com/?http://www.blah.com/blah

I have this code that adds after particular element URL's but I am not sure about adding for a pretence:

```
$("A.blah").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + '/blah';
});
```

Comment: Use this in the function: `return 'http://blankrefer.com/?' + href;`

Comment: why would you want to give all your traffic details to `blankrefer.com`? how can we trust them more than a site the user intends to visit? wouldn't it be better to remove the referer client-side if you didn't want the destination site to see the value? that way, nobody sees it...

Comment: I am  not using it to give all traffic details, but I am using it for particular things, by the way, im testing it on youtube and this is what happens  `http://blankrefer.com/?/watch?v=e_AcLEX11aI`

Comment: You will have to encode the URL that is after the `?`.

Comment: like so? `return 'http://blankrefer.com/?https://youtube.com' + href;`

Comment: is their not a more elegant way, to make it universal for anylink on the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

try this one, will change href for all anchors having blah class

```
$("A.blah").each(function(){
   $old_url = $(this).attr('href');
   $new_url = 'http://blankrefer.com/?'+$old_url;
   $(this).attr('href',$new_url);//changed this line
});
```

Comment: (youtube for testing) yes it is working, but doing the same thing as the first answer, `http://blankrefer.com/?/watch?v=e_AcLEX11aI`

Comment: this one is returning what and what u want 1 example from each?

Comment: I believe this is the problem I am now having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739832/

Comment: here is another Idea, using http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_appendto.asp with http://www.blankrefer.com/anonymize_script.html code